# Javascript string delimiter not escaped properly in listings

Tags: listings

I am trying to use `listings` to display Javascript code. Following the replies to [another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89574/language-option-supported-in-listings), I worked out the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{JavaScript}{
    keywords={break, case, catch, continue, debugger, default, delete, do, else, 
              finally, for, function, if, in, instanceof, new, return, switch, 
              this, throw, try, typeof, var, void, while, with},
    morekeywords={class, export, boolean, throw, implements, import, this},
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    string=[b]",
    morestring=[b]',
    sensitive=true
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines={true}, language={Javascript}, numbers=left]
var string = "This is special' string";
var alpha = document.selection;
str = str.replace(/[!.:?,;\"]/g, '');
dictionary_access ("" + t );
var alpha = document.selection;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

However the displayed listing does not have proper formatting (whitespaces being highlighted outside the string). I guess it is because the string delimiters are not escaped properly.

[image: listing output]

Someone else also had a [similar issue with Basic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116966/is-escaping-character-in-lstlisting-giving-wrong-output). I have tried replacing [b] in `string=[b]"` with `[bd]`, `[m]` for both single and double quote. Also tried using `string=[s]""` but no success.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Somewhat related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164858/how-can-i-highlight-a-freestanding-regexp-in-string-style/164867#164867

Answer (score 3):

It looks like what's going on is that `listings` is failing to recognize that the double quote in line 3 is inside a "string" (actually a regex, of course). As such, the double quote on line 3 opens a string literal that is closed by the first double quote on line 4, but then a new string literal is opened by the second double quote on line 4.

I think you should be able to fix this problem just by making `/` into a string delimiter. In other words, add

```
morestring=[b]/
```

to your `\lstdefinelanguage`.

There shouldn't be any issues with the interaction of `"` and `'` with `/`, since `/` doesn't need to be escaped in `"..."`, and vice versa.

Comment: I tried this but now have the issue that the symbol for division doesn't work for example:


number = number / 256; /* not a regex */

some_other_number = number / 2;