# Substitute text between delimiters (listings)

Tags: listings, substitution, lstdefinestyle

I want to format code within the `lstlistings` package via `\lstdefinestyle`.  The goal is to substitute the text after the regex `'C:\` up to the regex `.eps'` with `PATH`.

How can I realize this?

The solution should be as generic as possible, i.e. the text between the two is not constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [further research](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229060/can-i-use-moredelim-in-package-listings-to-fetch-a-regular-expression/455768#455768) and this [follow-up post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700284/ignore-text-between-bgroup-and-egroup-from-printing-in-pdf-during-runtime/700479#700479), I was able to find the following solution:

Add the following code to the main.tex:

```
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

\makeatletter

\let\orig@lst@DelimOpen=\lst@DelimOpen
\def\lst@DelimOpen#1#2#3#4#5#6\@empty{%
    \orig@lst@DelimOpen{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}\@empty
    \@delim@open@hook
}
\let\orig@lst@DelimClose=\lst@DelimClose
\def\lst@DelimClose{%
    \@delim@close@hook
    \orig@lst@DelimClose
}

\def\@delim@open@hook{%
    \def\@temp{\formatPATH}%
    \ifx\lst@currstyle\@temp
        \formatPATH@start
    \fi
}
\def\@delim@close@hook{%
    \def\@temp{\formatPATH}%
    \ifx\lst@currstyle\@temp
        \aftergroup\formatPATH@end
    \fi
}

\def\formatPATH{}
\def\formatPATH@start{{\color{mylilas} \textquotesingle C:\textbackslash... }{\bfseries\color{black} YOUR\_PATH}\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
\def\formatPATH@end{\egroup{\color{mylilas} \textquotesingle}}

\makeatother
```

And in the list where this formatting should be applied (e.g. `\lstdefinestyle`):

```
moredelim=[is][\formatPATH]{'C:\\}{.eps'},
```

So instead of the following output:

[image]

I was able to achieve this:

[image]

Thus the generic redaction of information works, thanks again!