# Ignore Text between \bgroup and \egroup from printing in PDF during runtime

Tags: delimiters, grouping, def, remove, hide

I would like to exclude the text between `\bgroup` and `\egroup` from appearing in the final PDF, i.e. mark it as a comment during runtime. However, the problem here is that the text is not static and `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are in two different command definitions.

How can I realize this specific behaviour?

Comment: why bgroup and egrouo? but you can put `\setbox0\vbox` before the `\bgroup`  most likely.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I am not from LaTeX community, but I would like to point out that `\bgroup` and `\egroup` are part of a lot of macros. You cannot simply re-define it. This is possible only in OpTeX where `\_broup` and `\_egroup` are used internally in macros and you can declare `\def\bgroup{\setbox0=\_vbox\_broup}` if you want to remove texts from `\bgroup`...`\egroup` used in your document.

Comment: Can you please add an example of the code you have?

Comment: @egreg The example where I needed this specific behavior was the following - at that time still unanswered - post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699936/substitute-text-between-delimiters-listings/700481#700481.

Comment: Voted to close also the other question for the same reason. The site is for solving a particular problem of yours, but the questions are supposed to be helpful to others having similar issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to a solution found with the help of @David Carlisle, I would like to conclude this post.

It was actually a simple addition of the command. Nothing more. No idea why it works, but it does. Thanks!

Enclosed is the full solution to the problem. The two definitions are triggered at a delimiter start and a delimiter end. Accordingly, everything between the two definitions, i.e. between `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, is now blacked out and replaced by `'YOUR_PATH'`:

```
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

\makeatletter

\def\formatPATH{}
\def\formatPATH@start{{\color{mylilas} \textquotesingle C:\textbackslash... }{\bfseries\color{black} YOUR\_PATH}\setbox0\vbox\bgroup}
\def\formatPATH@end{\egroup{\color{mylilas} \textquotesingle}}

\makeatother
```

A complete solution including the triggering of both definitions can be found in the following original post: [Substitute text between delimiters (listings)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699936/substitute-text-between-delimiters-listings)

Comment: That's not how this site works. As the aim is to build a library of knowledge for future users with the same problem, an answer ought to contain the solution to the problem, not just that you solved your problem. That's not really helpful to know for anybody but you.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I hope I was able to constructively implement your criticism of my conclusion and revise my questionable approach during the post finalization. My apologies, I just assumed the answer was already given in full.

Comment: Just curious: why not use actual regex (in expl3) to edit the path?

Comment: Or even just plain string replace (again, in expl3)?

Comment: @Cicada Because I am an absolute LaTeX beginner and have no idea - to put it in a nutshell. The solution seemed the best / easiest to me. I'm open to new and even better suggestions. Therefore, also just out of curiosity, the counter question: How would you have implemented it then - yes in expl3, and how?