Issue with \ cutting the lstlisting styling with Visual Basic
I have an issue with the \ character cutting the color styling for the rest of the code.
here is the parts of my code :
\documentclass{article}
%Packages mise en page
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, hmargin = 2cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{inconsolata}


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.23}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.18,0.9}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.82}

\lstdefinestyle{VBA}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},  
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=-1.5cm, xrightmargin=-1cm
}
\lstset{style=VBA}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language={[Visual]Basic}]
Sub ExportToXml()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim RootPath As String: RootPath = wb.path & "\"
        ' Test des entrees
    Dim row As Integer: row = 6
    Dim column As Integer: column = 3
    Dim ErrorType As Integertant
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}

The coloring works fine until the "\"


What I tried:

removing just the \ and it works fine
changing "" with '' and it works as well


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I edited it to add what you asked for

Did you test the exact same code as you show in the question? Does it compile for you?

Yes, it compiles but I still have the problem with \

There will be an error about using [...] in the preamble and begin{lstlisting} without the starting \ is also an error.

When I compile the code as given it shows ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. . Please modify the code so it produces the actual problem.

Also try to remove packages that are not needed to demonstrate the problem, most likely you need no packages at all except for listings itself and xcolor.

I modified the code in my post so now it is exactly what I used to compile

it is the same issue, it work now

You can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116968/36296 to solve the problem with \":
\documentclass{article}
%Packages mise en page
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, hmargin = 2cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{inconsolata}


\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.23}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0.13,0.18,0.9}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.82}

\lstdefinestyle{VBA}{
    language={[Visual]Basic},
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},  
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{codeblue},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    xleftmargin=-1.5cm, xrightmargin=-1cm,
    morestring=[s]""
}
\lstset{style=VBA}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Sub ExportToXml()
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim RootPath As String: RootPath = wb.path & "\"
        ' Test des entrees
    Dim row As Integer: row = 6
    Dim column As Integer: column = 3
    Dim ErrorType As Integertant
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


